# Numpy genfromtxt with multi-line data

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text file with each record being a 4x3 block of numeric values such as

```
1 1 1
1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0

2 2 2
2.0 2.0 2.0
2.0 2.0 2.0
2.0 2.0 2.0
```

I am trying to read these into a numpy structured array.  `genfromtext` and `loadtxt` both seem to want the data to be represented as a single row and not in the custom format the vendor is providing.  I know it is possible to read the lines via standard python, push every group of 4 lines into a single string, and then pass the string on to numpy, but I wonder if numpy natively supports this type of operation? I am not seeing anything in the [genfromtxt docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html).

For example, `genfromtxt(fname, skip_header=1, shape=(4,3), dtype=my_custom_dtype)`

Comment: If you want to provide the shape anyway, why don't you just perform a `reshape` after loading? Or do you want `genfromtext` to figure out the shape?

Answer (score 3):

I just put your data into a file and tested `loadtxt`. It read everything into a single array, which you then just have to split.

```
a = np.loadtxt(fname)
res = np.vsplit(a, a.shape[0]/4)
```

Comment: This ended being the solution - read natively and then use numpy to do the reshape.